# MySQL deleting from table if item from the being-deleted row meets a criteria

Tags: mysql, if-statement, rowdeleting

I am creating a site with admins that are allowed to delete a user if the users accesslevel is less than 8. I tried this as well as a few other solutions, but it doesn't work. How should I be going about this?
@id is defined previously in the same code, but is not the error. It is entered by the user.

```
SET @hi = SELECT IF(SELECT accesslevel FROM members WHERE id = 8 < @id, 1,0);
IF @hi == 1 THEN {DELETE FROM members WHERE id = @id}
END IF;
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Why would'nt a straight delete work? `DELETE FROM members WHERE id = @id AND accesslevel < 8`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Completely spaced AND. Changed it to:

```
DELETE FROM members WHERE id = @id AND accesslevel < 8;
```

Code works as needed now.